# How do you launch a web authentication window within Unity for a UWP app?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, twitter, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to use the [Twitter Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/services/Twitter) from the [UWPCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit), which I have running as a standalone UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app, but when I import it into Unity (2017.2.0f3) as a library, it doesn't open the authentication window.

This is what shows up on the working standalone UWP app:

[image: What should happen]

When in unity, it seems to go through the setup code, but not run this line properly:

```
var result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, startUri, endUri);
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Services/Services/Twitter/TwitterDataProvider.cs#L293

It just returns `WebAuthenticationStatus.UserCancel`, whereas on the standalone UWP, it'd return `WebAuthenticationStatus.Success`. Note, it also returns `WebAuthenticationStatus.UserCancel` on the standalone UWP app when the user clicks the close button on the pop up.

Is it possible to run `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker) in Unity? Are there any other ways to do web authentication on the Windows platform using Unity?

I've also tried [TwitterKit](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/unity/installation), but unfortunately, it doesn't have support for Windows UWP (only iOS and Android).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to Twitter supports UWP. It has a `UniversalAuthorizer` that works like this:

```
    private async void TweetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var authorizer = new UniversalAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore
            {
                ConsumerKey = "",
                ConsumerSecret = ""
            }
        };

        await authorizer.AuthorizeAsync();
        var ctx = new TwitterContext(authorizer);

        string userInput = tweetText.Text;
        Status tweet = await ctx.TweetAsync(userInput);

        ResponseTextBlock.Text = tweet.Text;

        await new MessageDialog("You Tweeted: " + tweet.Text, "Success!").ShowAsync();
    }
```

Check out the Samples folder for a complete listing: https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter

Comment: Does this work in Unity? The UWPCommunityToolkit works fine as a UWP app too, just not in unity, which is my problem.